# Why don't my assets show up running in production on my laptop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My production Rails 4.2.3 application has assets that are not behaving correctly. I'm getting a bunch of misses on just a few assets. Naturally, they show up well enough in development.

So I thought I would just try to run the app in production on my laptop. I ran:

rake assets:precompile
And fired up the server with:

RAILS_ENV=production rails s
and yikes! There are NO assets showing up. The screen is just an absolute mess. Why is this so difficult, and what can I do to actually see the application the way it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 3):

By default, Rails does not serve assets when in production mode. Instead, it assumes that you have a separate web server (e.g. Nginx) configured to serve the assets out of the `public/assets` directory.

If you want to be able to see assets when running `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`, then you need to change this setting:

```
# In config/environments/production.rb
config.serve_static_files = true
```

Now when you do this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

You should see the assets.

Comment: Why to process static assets through the rails in production?